# How to add a new host to existing Apache Ignite instance?

Tags: java, ignite

I am trying few examples with Apache Ignite. I am feeding the addresses for my Ignite node in this format

```
ipFinderTcpIp.setAddresses(memberStrings); // ipFinderTcpIp is of TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder class
spi.setIpFinder(ipFinderTcpIp); //spi is of TcpDiscoverySpi class 
config.setDiscoverySpi(spi); //config is of IgniteConfiguration class
//memberStrings contains the ipv4 addresses in String format. It is a collection. 

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(config);
```

The values for memberStrings are taken from an input file
I want to add an address dynamically to the ignite node. For the sake of simplicity let us say ignite is already running in addresses A and B, both of which are present in memberStrings. The topology snapshot looks like

```
Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=8, offheap=4.5GB, heap=3.6GB]
```

Let's say i add a new address 'C' to the input file. I have a running thread which detects this change and makes the change in memberStrings. How do i make sure C is also present in the topology without stopping and restarting the ignite instance to run the above piece of code again??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you don't need to add this address 'C' to the configuration of the first node. At the moment of start, node C will try to connect to the all addresses from its list and it doesn't need to have its address in config of the node 'A'. So, the node will join the cluster without any problem.

In some cases may be useful to share all IP addresses between all nodes, using 'shared' flag: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/vm/TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder.html#setShared-boolean-
i.e., this flag can be used for clients - at the moment of reconnecting, it will try to reconnect to all nodes in cluster.

Additionally, if you don't know all the addresses before start, you can use other implementations of IpFinder: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery

Comment: A, B and C are not ignite nodes. They are all addresses to the same ignite node. The only difference is that C is being added after the ignite node is up (i.e A and B). 

Should I stop the ignite instance, change the ignite configuration(include C in memberStrings) and restart ignite or can it be done in any other way??

Comment: How did you add address to the node after start?

Comment: IpFinder contains addresses of the nodes in cluster, not the all addresses of the local node

Comment: Not adding addresses to the node.. I am adding the new address in the input file which will update the collection 'MemberStrings'
********************************
""""How did you add address to the node after start?""""
This is exactly what i want to know.  Is there any way to add the address without stopping ignite

Comment: Why do you need to add addresses after the node start? What kind of addresses do you want to add? Addresses of the new nodes?

Comment: OK I realized my mistake. When I used an IgniteCluster and printed all the addresses in each node, I see that all of them are different(i.e A and B belong to different nodes). So in the end your method worked. In C node, I configured the cluster with all 3 addresses and started ignite in C. The topology change reflected in both A and B and they did not have to restart.