# How can I setup apache ignite nodes in a cluster using dynamically provided IPs

Tags: ignite

Basically I want to create a cluster of 5 nodes as of now but I can add or remove more nodes(at a later time maybe). So I don't want to provide static IPs as given in the documentation provided on their site.
How can I do so or what is the best approach possible for this scenario? Any feasible approach or initiative would be highly appreciable.
P.S. : I'm a bit new with Apache Ignite.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Evgenii answer here:

[How to add a new host to existing Apache Ignite instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247587/how-to-add-a-new-host-to-existing-apache-ignite-instance)

Also you can read the next articles:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/zookeeper-discovery

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite uses [DiscoverySpi](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/DiscoverySpi.java) for cluster node discovery. For a cluster with 10's of nodes, [tcpDiscoverySPI](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/TcpDiscoverySpi.java) could be used. tcpDiscoverySPI uses [tcpDiscoveryIpFinder](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/TcpDiscoveryIpFinder.java)
to get the list of cluster nodes.

Apart from Static and Multicast, there are different ipfinder implementations that could be used. One such implementation is [JDBC based ipfinder](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery#section-jdbc-based-ip-finder).

```
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

// Configure your DataSource.
DataSource someDs = MySampleDataSource(...);

TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder();

ipFinder.setDataSource(someDs);

spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

// Override default discovery SPI.
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);

// Start Ignite node.
Ignition.start(cfg);
```

If you go with this approach, each node on the start-up will register its own IP address in the metadata table. These table entries would be used for discovery. This way, you do not need to have static IP addresses in your configurations

Answer (score 0):

Ignite configuration consists of Java objects (of type `IgniteConfiguration`, etc) so you can populate it with dynamically provided IPs in runtime before starting your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Zookeeper based discovery.

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/zookeeper-discovery